# 301 redirection showing the old page URL in the query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the below code in my website and it's working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /a/b/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am able to access my website like

```
https://www.example.com/a/b/testing
```

Now, I am getting issues with 301 redirections.

I have tried below code

```
Redirect 301 /oldurl /newurl
```

but while accessing the URL I am getting below URL

```
https://www.example.com/a/b/newurl?slug=oldurl
```

My expected output is the below URL.

```
https://www.example.com/a/b/newurl
```

Comment: In what _order_ did you put those directives? If changing the order doesn't help, then I would recommend to do the redirect using a RewriteRule as well, instead of via the `Redirect` dirctive.

Comment: @CBroe, I have added it at the bottom.

Comment: And, have you checked if changing the order helps? (Make sure you don't get fooled by an earlier faulty redirect your browser might have already cached - clear cache, or test in a private tab/window.)

Comment: Yes, I have cleared all the cache and checked In the private browser... Now i am not getting slug=oldurl but redirection not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid mixing `Redirect` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) directives in the same context as you can get these unexpected conflicts. mod_rewrite is processed before mod_alias, despite the apparent order of the directives in the config and `Redirect` works on the requested URL-path (not the rewritten URL-path and not the query string).

So, what is happening when requesting `/oldurl` and you use `Redirect 301 /oldurl /newurl` together with the existing mod_rewrite rewrite is:

1. mod_rewrite internally rewrites the request to `index.php?slug=oldurl`
2. `Redirect` creates a redirect from `/oldurl` (the originally requested URL-path) to `/newurl`

   - The query string (if any) is appended to the target URL. This is now `slug=oldurl` since mod_rewrite modified it.
3. Resulting URL is `/newurl?slug=oldurl`.

(As noted above, this is regardless of the order of the directives, since they are from two different modules.)

#### Solution

You need to use mod_rewrite for the redirect as well and this must go *before* the existing rewrite (the order is important, since the directives belong to the *same* module). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /a/b/

RewriteRule ^oldurl$ /newurl [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any query string that might be present on `/oldurl` is preserved. eg. `/oldurl?foo=bar` is redirected to `/newurl?foo=bar` (as it would do with `Redirect`). If you specifically want to remove any query string then include the `QSD` flag (Query String Discard) on the redirect (first) rule.

NB: I removed the trailing `/?` on the regex since it is entirely redundant. Since you made the token optional and the preceding quantifier is *greedy* then `.*` would consume the *optional* trailing slash anyway. If the intention was to exclude the trailing slash (if any) from the captured subpattern then you need to make the preceding quantifier non-greedy. eg. `(.*?)/?$` (the start-of-string anchor is not required).

(I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root - it looks like it is, from the erroneous redirect you were getting, although the `/a/b/` prefix is slightly confusing - see below)

---

*Aside:*

> I have tried below code
>
> ```
> Redirect 301 /oldurl /newurl
> ```
>
> but while accessing the URL I am getting below URL
>
> ```
> https://www.example.com/a/b/newurl?slug=oldurl
> ```

I would have expected this to have resulted in `/newurl?slug=oldurl`, not `/a/b/newurl?slug=oldurl`?

Comment: Sorry, This is working for me. Thank you so much.. Upvote from my side..